# Does Pytorch-Lightning have a multiprocessing (or Joblib) module?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-lightning

I have been googling around but can't seem to find if there is a `multiprocessing` module available in Pytorch-Lightning, just like how Pytorch has a `torch.multiprocessing` module.

Does anyone know if Pytorch-Lightning has this (or a `Joblib` similar) module? I am looking for a Pytorch-Lightning module which allows me to parallelize over multiple GPUs

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:** To be more specific, I am looking for a `multiprocessing` module in Pytorch-Lightning which allows me to parallelize over multiple GPUs on non-neural network computations, such as:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool

X = np.array([[1, 3, 2, 3], [2, 3, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
X = torch.DoubleTensor(X)

def X_power_func(j):
    X_power = X.cuda()**j
    return X_power

if __name__ == '__main__':
  with Pool(processes = 2) as p:   # Parallelizing over 2 GPUs
    results = p.map(X_power_func, range(4))

results
```

Comment: I am thinking of the same thing. Basically I need to run non-training process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, basically all you have to do is to provide [`Trainer`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/trainer.html) with appropriate argument `gpus=N` and specify backend:

```
# train on 8 GPUs (same machine (ie: node))
trainer = Trainer(gpus=8, distributed_backend='ddp')

# train on 32 GPUs (4 nodes)
trainer = Trainer(gpus=8, distributed_backend='ddp', num_nodes=4)
```

You can read more about it in [multi-GPU training documentation](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multi_gpu.html).

### EDIT:

What you were actually looking for is `distributed` module instead of `multiprocessing`, `torch.distributed.DistributedDataParallel` is usually recommended for parallelizing over multiple GPUs.

Comment: Thanks @Szymon Maszke. The reason why I am looking for a `multiprocessing` module in Pytorch-Lightning is so that I can parallelize over multiple GPUs on non-neural net stuff. If my understanding is correct `Trainer()' allows you to parallelize over GPUs on neural net models, not on non-neural net stuff. I have updated my post with an example. Sorry I should have been clearer. Do you know if Pytorch-Lightning has a module which allows me to parallelize over multiple GPUs on non-neural net stuff?